# primarySwatch isn't setting primaryColor

Tags: flutter, themes

I have read that primaryColor is a Color, primarySwatch is MaterialColor, which includes various set of a Color.

first, according to my flutter class, I set Theme like this

```
primarySwatch: Colors.pink,
        accentColor: Colors.amber,
```

and when I set splashColor of InkWell, it worked.

```
splashColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
```

but the VsCode suggest me a better way, and automatically migrated Theme like this

```
colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(primarySwatch: Colors.pink)
               .copyWith(secondary: Colors.amber),
```

But the new way does not changes primaryColor of splashColor, I checked it Through By print the Color, but the Color was 0xff2196f3, which is default I think(close to blue).

so Why the new way does not set primaryColor?

Comment: You like the change splash color of inkwell  through materialApp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in new way, you should use it like this:

```
splashColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
```